# MP4 video plays on localhost but not after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, mp4

I made a video using Camtasia Studio 8. I added it to my MVC App and ran it on local host, video plays fine.  I publish to my local dev web server (windows server 2008), the video will not play. Gives no error.  I have tried on chrome and IE11.  On chrome I checked the network tab and it says "Status - Cancelled".  Do I need to make some changes on the web server settings?

```
            <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
                <source src="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/3_Comments_Letters.mp4")" />
            </video>
```

Comment: Is the browser making a web request to /Content/videos/3_Comments_Letters.mp4?

Comment: Yes, per the request url info

Comment: @BattlFrog Did you ever find a solution to this? I am have the same issue with a Camtasia Studio Video. Thanks :)

Comment: You have to add the mp4 MIME type to the web server. I found the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1470612.aspx?How+to+enable+IIS+to+play+MP4+files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to add the mp4 MIME type to the web server.  I found the answer here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1470612.aspx?How+to+enable+IIS+to+play+MP4+files

Answer (score 1):

Video not playing in server because the mime type is not added in IIS.

To add Mime Type :

•   Go to IIS and select your site

•   Click Mime Types Under menu and click Add on right side tab

•   Under File Name Extension add mp4,under Mime type add video/mp4 and click Ok.

•   Restart IIS ,Now run the application

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The source should be an attribute on the video node.

`<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/3_Comments_Letters.mp4")"></video>`

Comment: I tried that too, no help.  I will recompile the video and replace the existing file, maybe there was an error in production.